# I want my delete button to remove last character in the string. Substring and slice not working as expected in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to js.And I'm making a simple calculator. Everything's working fine except delete button.I want the delete button to remove last character in the string. So I used both slice and substring method. But both aren't working. Is there something wrong in my code

```js
let num = document.querySelector("#num");
let answer = document.querySelector("#answer");

let p = document.querySelector("#demo");
let numKeys = document.querySelectorAll(".numKeys");

let operator = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
let removeNum = document.querySelector(".delete");

let clear = document.querySelector(".clear")

let btnValue = 0;
let numValue = "";

let called;

function numValues() {
    let numKeyValue = Number(this.innerHTML);
    if (num.value === "") {
        numValue += numKeyValue;
    } else if (called  === true) {
            num.value = "";
            called = false;
            numValue += numKeyValue;
        } else {
            numValue += numKeyValue;
        }

    num.value += numKeyValue;
    console.log(numValue);
}

function operators(){
    let add = this.value;
    numValue += add;
    called = true;
}

function result() {
    num.value = eval(numValue); 
}

function remove() {
    numValue.substring(0, numValue.length -1);
    console.log(numValue);
}

function clearAll() {
    numValue = "";
    num.value = "";
}

for (let i=0; i<numKeys.length; i++){
    numKeys[i].addEventListener("click", numValues)
}

for (let i=0; i<operator.length; i++) {
    operator[i].addEventListener("click", operators);
}

answer.addEventListener("click", result);

removeNum.addEventListener("click", remove);

clear.addEventListener("click", clearAll);
```

Comment: can you add the html to your question?

Comment: `substring` and `slice` return a new string, they don't do the job in place.

Comment: ah, I want to but it keeps saying that i should add more details in order to publish

Comment: Teemu is right, you need to make a variable to take the new value, slice and substring don't edit the actual string.

Comment: oh! I see. so what method should i use to remove last character of my string?

Comment: the same one you're doing, loop's answer should work.

Comment: thanks guys. I just  solved the problem by giving it new variable and added to the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numValue = numValue.substring(0, numValue.length -1);
```